# INFORMATICA POWERCENTER: Mapping issue and XML output

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, mapping, workflow, informatica-powercenter

I'm a beginner with Powercenter, and I want to convert a relation output result into a xml file.
I have a xsd file with the xml structure.
When I import it into Designer, PWC create automatically the target, but when I validate the mapping, I received this error:

```
         The XML view [X_Data] is projected but it is not reachable from a root view.
```

XML Definition is correct and it's valid [XML_Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzAuw.png)

Here the mapping

I found this solution but I don't know what to do [Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04jgN.png)

Please can you explain me where is the issue ?
Thank you for support

UPDATE: I think I've found the solution. In the mapping, I've add 2 sequence generator and link them to element root of xml, XPK_Statistics (and FK_Statistics) and XPK_Records (FK_records). I link CURRVAL field and not NEXTVAL because during previous executions, the record data wasn't populated correctly (they were being read from the database, but not write into xml).

This is my mapping now: [mapping update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VR1X.png)

With this solution, I can add more source table and obtain only ONE xml like this: [xml_complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE8lM.png)

Here the complete xsd (maybe it's useful for someone):
[xsd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFyLC.png)

Comment: i think you need to link those XPK_* columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill in the PKs and FKs. `Country` and `ID` are part of `Data`, that is a part of `Records` structure. It's a one-to-many relationship. And with no PK/FK given, PowerCenter is not able to tell to which parent the child structure belongs to.

Think of it this way perhaps: assume there will be 3 input rows, each having a pair of `Country` and `ID` columns. Should they go to three separate `Records` or all be a part of the same one? Perhaps first and second pair should go to one `Records` structure, and third pair to another instance of it? How to tell?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. I edit my question with solution. During execution, into session log, there are a lot of error (Row rejected due to duplicate primary key) but the solution it's working. I believe that duplication errors are arise from link with currval, but with nextval the output file was wrong

Comment: Job well done! Updating with your working solution is great! Now for the issues: they arise due to the fact that you're assigning same PK to diffrent groups. The key here is to generate just one group with the given PK. Perhaps you could aggregate? Think both in terms of having single group as input as well as of having multiple groups, where different PKs should be generated. Long story short: use NextVal, but make sure there is appropriate number of groups (1, in this particular case).